# JS - Stop a number from incrementing

Tags: javascript

I have a small JS game that I am working on. I have something incrementing by 1 per second. Is there a way to stop it from incrementing and then continue the incrementing when another condition is met?

Comment: what all have you tried? post your code.

Comment: @Xero, `button` refers to a button.

Comment: If you try to define `oldIncrement` when `IncrementPs` is not defined, it will have the value `undefined`...  Vice-versa for defining `IncrementPs`

Comment: @Xero, It's a code snip-it. I did define it. The point of the post was the ask how to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of how you're doing your timing, but maybe if you only perform the increment when the button is enabled:

```
if (button.enabled) {
    IncrementPs += X;
}
```

Then it skips the incrementing when button is disabled.